# If the sum of $n$ cubes is zero, then the sum must be no larger than $\frac n3$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Assume that $a_1,...a_n$ are real numbers and $-1 \leq a_i\leq 1$ for $1\leq i\leq  n$. If $$a_1^3+\ldots +a_n^3=0$$ Then show that $$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n\le n/3$$

I just came cross this problem the other day. I totally have no idea how to prove it. Are there any hints about which theorem, principle or method to apply?

Comment: If the sum is zero, then it's certainly less than 3/n. I assume your question should be: if $$a_1^3+\cdots +a_n^3=0$$ with $|a_i|\le 1$ then $$a_1+\cdots +a_n \le 3/n$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $\let\leq\leqslant\let\geq\geqslant$that this is a question (day 2 problem 3) from the IMC (International Mathematics Competition for University Students) 1999.

The most elegant solution I know is the following: (It turns out that this is just the [official solution](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1999/prob_sol2.pdf), so (down)vote accordingly.)

For $x\geq-1$, $$x^3-\frac34x+\frac14=(x+1)\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\geq0.$$ Hence $$(a_1^3+\cdots+a_n^3)-\frac34(a_1+\cdots+a_n)+\frac n4\geq0,$$ that is, $$a_1+\cdots+a_n\leq\frac n3.$$

---

You could have come up with this solution if only you had the idea of considering an appropriate cubic $x^3+ax+b$ (with the above strategy in mind) which satisfies

- It is positive for $-1\leq x\leq 1$.
- If we sum up for $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ we should obtain $a_1+\cdots+a_n\leq\frac n4$. This means it is necessary that $a=-3b$.
- You could guess another condition such as that it has a factor $x+1$ (perhaps because a condition $a\geq-1$ in an equality is unusual). This gives $b=\frac14$.

Hence a possible cubic would be $x^3-\frac34x+\frac14$. Indeed, it works.

**Note:** examining the equality case should also help you find the appropriate cubic. Observe that equality holds for $n=9k$ and $8k$ of the numbers are $\frac12$, $k$ of them are $-1$. This tells us what the roots of the cubic should be.

Comment: how did you got the step written after "that is"

Comment: By filling in $a_1^3 + \cdots + a_n^3 = 0$ and rearranging.

Answer (score 4):

This problem seems to be wrongly stated.  Suppose that $a_1,\ldots,a_{27} = 1/3$ and $a_{28} = -1$.  Then $\sum a_i^3 = 27/27 - 1 = 0$, but $\sum a_i = 27/3 - 1 = 8 \gt \frac{3}{28}$.

Perhaps the intended bound was $n/3$ rather than $3/n$?

Comment: You are right. It was a typo. It should be n/3.